# I am not able to get the gridview populated with textview in Android Fragment

Tags: java, android, gridview, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

i am not able to populate the imageview textview inside gridview using fragments.

It is showing blank intead of gridview populating in my project can please anyone see the code below and let me know what i have to change

And the populating the image and text is from the mysql database dynamically

```
public class StoreHomeFragment extends Fragment {
final ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> MyArrList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.store_home, container, false);
    final GridView gridView1 = (GridView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.store_home_gridview); 
    gridView1.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(rootView.getContext(), MyArrList));
    return rootView;
}
```

//Activity is created

```
@Override

 public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

     String url = "http://192.168.1.132/Android/App/good.php"; //url where i am using select query and retrieving it from database

        try {
            JSONArray data = new JSONArray(getJSONUrl(url));

            HashMap<String, String> map;

            for(int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++){
                JSONObject c = data.getJSONObject(i);//retrieving from db
                map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                map.put("name", c.getString("name"));
                map.put("artist", c.getString("artist"));
                map.put("price", c.getString("price"));
                map.put("image", c.getString("image"));


                MyArrList.add(map);
            }           

            //gridView1.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this,MyArrList));

        } catch (JSONException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

//I have used imageAdapter

```
class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter 

{
    private Context context;
    public ImageView imageView;
    private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> MyArr = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    public ImageAdapter(Context c,ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list) 
    {   
        context = c;

        MyArr = list;
    }

    public int getCount() {

        return MyArr.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {

        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {

        return position;
    }
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.store_home_gridview_row, null); 
        }

        TextView tv_title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textview_name);
        tv_title.setText("Title:"+MyArr.get(position).get("name"));

        TextView tv_artist = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textview_artist);
        tv_artist.setText("Artist:"+MyArr.get(position).get("artist"));

        TextView tv_duration = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textview_price);
        tv_duration.setText("Price:"+MyArr.get(position).get("price"));

        String abc = (MyArr.get(position).get("image"));
        String abcd = "http://192.168.1.132/images/products/"+abc;

        imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        try
        {
            URL url3 = null;
            try {
                url3 = new URL(abcd);
                } catch (Exception e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url3.openConnection().getInputStream()); //image is populated 
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bmp);
        }
        catch(Exception par)
        {
            imageView.setImageResource(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_report_image);
        }
        return convertView;         
    }

} 



    /*** Get JSON Code from URL ***/
    public String getJSONUrl(String url) {
        StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
        try 
        {
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpGet);
            StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
            int statusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();
            System.out.println ( "status Code : " + statusCode );
            if (statusCode == 200) 
            { 
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                InputStream content = entity.getContent();
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(content));
                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) 
                {
                    str.append(line);
                }
            }   
            else 
            {
                Log.e("Log", "Failed to download file..");
            }
        } 
        catch (ClientProtocolException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        catch (IOException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println ( "str : " + str.toString() );
        return str.toString();
    }


 }
```

Comment: This code must throwing NetworkOnMainThreadException. See the log

Comment: s correct i tried all the ways to add it into activity but i am getting blank xml in app @BirajZalavadia

Comment: Pls tell me where i must correct this one @BirajZalavadia

Comment: you need to call webservice in asynctask

Comment: where can u pls paste the code where i have to edit and at the top where i have to change because i used one code it is working but i cant add json object to it so asking in depth and the code is correct only right @BirajZalavadia

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow the steps Hope this helps you

1) Remove these lines from onCreateView() method

```
final GridView gridView1 = (GridView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.store_home_gridview); 
    gridView1.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(rootView.getContext(), MyArrList));
```

2)Modify `onActivityCreated()` as follow

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            String url = "http://192.168.1.132/Android/App/good.php";

            try {
                JSONArray data = new JSONArray(getJSONUrl(url));

                HashMap<String, String> map;

                for (int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = data.getJSONObject(i);

                    map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    map.put("name", c.getString("name"));
                    map.put("artist", c.getString("artist"));
                    map.put("price", c.getString("price"));
                    map.put("image", c.getString("image"));

                    MyArrList.add(map);
                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (Exception e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            final GridView gridView1 = (GridView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.store_home_gridview);
            gridView1.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(getActivity(), MyArrList));

        }
    }.execute();
}
```

Comment: WHAT ABOUT IMAGEADAPTER PAL is it correct no need to change that one right @Biraj Zalavadia

Comment: Ya i have one doubt can we add mediaplayer inside imageadapter @Biraj Zalavadia

Comment: you mean to say want to play music on image click?

Comment: ya correct and it will be also dynamic from database only @Biraj Zalavadia

Comment: for that you no need to add mediaplayer in image adapter. Just create one method which get the music file path from database and start playing. And call that method on gridview item click

Comment: oh k k then it is fine @Biraj Zalavadia if i have doubt can i ask you again in android can i get your email id

Comment: i cant popup the image it is going to catch block in above code

Comment: you are getting again NetwrokOnMainThreadException because you are trying to download image from UI thread inside ImageAdapter class

Comment: ya i guess how to rectify it friend can u help me in populatiing the image only image is not populating rest text view is populating correctly @Biraj Zalavadia

Comment: do one thing there is readymade framework "androidquery" to do this job efficiently and fast. Download jar put in libs folder and start using https://code.google.com/p/android-query/downloads/list

Comment: no no image is not showing correctly no error as such pls tell me where i must edit in this above code in image adapter it is going to the catch block and displaying image it is not going inside imageView.context try block @Biraj Zalavadia . it will be easy if i edit here itself